# React Hook Form in reusable component for different field

Tags: react-hook-form

I want to create this kind of form.

```
       update
    -----------
    |         v
---------------------
| Data   |          |
|--------|          |         ------------
| row 1  | reusable |  open   | reusable |
| row 2  | property | ------> |   Modal  |
| row 3  |   grid   |         ------------
| row n  |          |
---------------------
```

Example layout ( not mine )

[image]

So the property grid will show a form base on row click from.
The form data already loaded way before this layout is render in the provider.
On clicking the row it will set an `activeIndex` state that will be use by provider grid component to access useFieldArray data using `` register(`param.${activeIndex}`) ``. For this case it works correctly.

Now some of the property require more complex layout. So I need to show in a separate  modal. This modal will be open by the button inside on of the property in the property grid.

To reduce element I want to reuse the modal just like the property grid. using useMemo or useEffect to update what value appear on the modal when the index is updated.

In this modal the data will be base on the activeIndex and another additional index,  something like `` register(`param.${activeIndex}.subparam.${subIndex}`) ``.

When testing the modal

1. select row 1
2. open modal using property A
3. set value
4. close modal
5. select row 2
6. open modal using property A
7. set value
8. close modal
9. select row 1
10. open modal using property A
11. **value of property A from row 2 is shown here**
12. try submitting the whole form, all value is correct

Any example / approach for this case ?
example code is pending.

Comment: [Demo](https://codepen.io/wiryono/pen/KKGrQjy) here